# Get S3 key with max date based on key path

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket with 100K files. Each file key follows the pattern `/foo/<date as YYYYMMDD>/bar/<"sample" | "test">/foobar.csv`.

I am trying to write a Python script to retrieve the key(s) which include "sample" in path and the minimum date.

I was exploring [boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html) but only found a way to get this pulling all the keys with prefix `/foo/` and then do the filtering in the Python side.

Is there any other way to only pull the key(s) of interest?